# Ошибка E0137 Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++, строки

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    Bomb b;
    b.weight = rand() % 100;
    b.color = "red"; // Ошибка E0137
    b.tnt = rand() % 1000;
    bombs.push_back(b);
}
```

При b.color == "red"; ошибка исчезает, но слово "red" в консоль не выводится.
Можете, пожалуйста, помочь решить данную проблему.

КОД:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Bomb {
    float weight;
    char color[10];
    float tnt;
};

struct DynamicArray {
    Bomb* data;
    int capacity;
    int current_size;

    DynamicArray() {
        capacity = 1;
        current_size = 0;
        data = new Bomb[capacity];
    }

    ~DynamicArray() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    void resize() {
        capacity *= 2;
        Bomb* newData = new Bomb[capacity];
        memcpy(newData, data, current_size * sizeof(Bomb));
        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }

    void push_back(Bomb element) {
        if (current_size == capacity) {
            resize();
        }
        data[current_size++] = element;
    }

    Bomb pop_back() {
        if (current_size == 0) {
            cout << "Error: array is empty" << endl;
            return Bomb{};
        }
        Bomb element = data[current_size--];
        return element;
    }

    Bomb get(int n) {
        if (n < 0 || n >= current_size) {
            cout << "Error: index out of bounds." << endl;
            return Bomb{};
        }
        return data[n];
    }

    int size() {
        return current_size;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < current_size; i++) {
            cout << "Bomb " << i << ": weight=" << data[i].weight << ", color=" << data[i].color << ", tnt=" << data[i].tnt << endl;
        }
    }

    void clear() {
        delete[] data;
        capacity = 1;
        current_size = 0;
        data = new Bomb[capacity];
    }

    void push_front(Bomb element) {
        if (current_size == capacity) {
            resize();
        }
        for (int i = current_size; i > 0; i--) {
            data[i] = data[i - 1];
        }
        data[0] = element;
        current_size++;
    }

    Bomb pop_front() {
        if (current_size == 0) {
            cout << "Error: cannot pop from empty array." << endl;
            return Bomb{};
        }
        Bomb element = data[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < current_size - 1; i++) {
            data[i] = data[i + 1];
        }
        current_size--;
        return element;
    }
};

int main() {
    DynamicArray bombs;
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        Bomb b;
        b.weight = rand() % 100;
        b.color = "red";
        b.tnt = rand() % 1000;
        bombs.push_back(b);
    }
    clock_t endTime = clock();
    double seconds = (double(endTime - startTime)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Add 50000 items to the end: " << seconds << " s" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Охотно! как только вы поможете мне разобраться... `int i = 5; int j = i*i;` Но когда я пишу `cout << d.first;`, выводится не 15, а -3. Как мне исправить ошибку?  Надеюсь, вы простите мне эти две строки, которые должны пояснить вам, что то, что вы написали, совершенно не содержит нужной для решения вашей проблемы информации... Что такое `Bomb`, никому не известно, как вы пытаетесь выводить в консоль и что — тоже...

Comment: @Harry, да согласен, непонятно что к чему, моя ошибка, извините.

Comment: Массив (это `"red"`) нельзя копировать. Используйте strcpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `Bomb.color` — это массив с заранее заданным размером

```
char color[10];
```

а вы пытаетесь присваивать ему, как будто это указатель. C-строки следует копировать с помощью специальных функций, например:

```
strcpy(b.color,"red");
```

Visual C++ может попросить вас использовать более безопасную версию — `strcpy_s`.

Или использовать строки С++ —

```
string color;
```

Насколько ваш код верен семантически, не разбирался; после указанного исправления он компилируется; на этом я и остановился.

Comment: Очень благодарен!